# Preventing Email Spoofing

Tags: email, spam, g-suite, spoofing

I use Google Apps with my domain.

Recently, we have begun to receive spam that gets past Google's spam filters.  They are *from* our own email addresses.

I am wondering how to prevent this kind of email spoofing.

We use an SPF record with the "~all" setting.  I'm wondering if I can upgrade that to "-all".  However, Google Apps recommends against it.  Also, I'm not 100% sure that our SPF record is complete.

Any suggestions?

Thank you ever so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can set your SPF record to `v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com -all` and it should work fine. Google is just covering their butt in case they change a mail relay's IP without changing their SPF record first.